# Convert a scraped string containing comma into an integer using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, integer, valueerror

Im trying to scrape the number of followers count with selenium but it clearly identify the "ValueError" as a number:

Snapshot:

[image]

Code trials:

```
follower_count =int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/a/span[1]/span').text)
following_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[1]/span').text)
```

The error message:

[image]

Comment: 1,961 has a comma which you should deal with.

Comment: You can use regular expression sub to clean your string so it's only numbers. After importing re. newstring = re.sub('[^0-9]','', oldstring)

Comment: @luthervespers i have this :  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\InstaPy-master\quickstart.py", line 79, in <module>
    followers_count = re.sub('[^0-9]','', follower_count)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 2):

The extracted text i.e. **1,961** contains a `,` character in between. So you won't be able to invoke `int()` directly on it.

---

### Solution

You need to `replace()` the `,` character from the text **1,961** first and then invoke `int()` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # count = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/a/span[1]/span').text
  count = "1,961"
  print(int(count.replace(",","")))
  print(type(int(count.replace(",",""))))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1961
  <class 'int'>
  ```

---

### This usecase

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
follower_count =int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/a/span[1]/span').text.replace(",",""))
following_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[1]/span').text.replace(",",""))
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How use re.sub to convert selenium string to an Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983982/how-use-re-sub-to-convert-selenium-string-to-an-integer/65985453#65985453)