# How use re.sub to convert selenium string to an Integer

Tags: python, selenium, integer, substring, typeerror

I am really desperate his last days to convert my string numbers value to a integer, so i try this :

Snapshot:

[image]

Code trials:

```
follower_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text)
convert_follower_count = re.sub('[^0-9]','', follower_count)
```

... is not working :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Desktop\TwitPy\quickstart.py", line 79, in <module>
   followers_count = re.sub('[^0-9]','', follower_count)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
   return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Your `follower_count` is an int. You can't replace characters in it, because it doesn't contain characters. It's a number.

Answer (score 1):

The extracted text i.e. **1,961** contains a `,` character in between. So you won't be able to invoke `int()` directly on it.

---

### Solution

You can can use `sub()` from [re](/questions/tagged/re) to replace the `,` character from the text **1,961** first and then invoke `int()` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # follower_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text)
  count = "1,961"

  import re
  print(int(re.sub(',', '', count)))
  print(type(int(re.sub(',', '', count))))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1961
  <class 'int'>
  ```

---

### This usecase

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
follower_count = int(re.sub(',', '', browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text))
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Convert a scraped string containing comma into an integer using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974990/convert-a-scraped-string-containing-comma-into-an-integer-using-python/65985135#65985135)

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError here is because you have converted follower_count into an integer and then passed it to re.sub that accept only string or bytes-like object.
You should check the output of browser.find_element_by_xpat and see if it's a string. If it is, you should not encounter any error. If it's a list or an object from selenium you might have to do a little bit more than just pass follower_count to re.sub

```
follower_count = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span').text
convert_follower_count = int(re.sub('[^0-9]','', follower_count))
```