# Selenium convert format number " k " (thousand) python to get title

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, type-conversion, integer

I would like to extract with selenium, the numbers follower on instagram but the "k" format (thousand) preclude me to get this.

[image]

So i trying this on python :

```
 follower_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li//a//span[contains(@title]").text)
```

but it doesn't work, i think either replace "k" by integer or use `find_element_by_xpath()` to extract the "int" on the title

Comment: xpath looks invalid. Please show a [mcve] with runnable code and the markup as text, not a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: .get_attribute('title') would produce 170,125 and then just use .replace(",","") and you'd get 170125 and then you use int.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your xpath. It seem incorrect to me.
Re-check it and use get_attribute() to get the value of the title, remove the "," then convert it to int data type.

```
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/barked/")
    
    # get title value
    follower = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//header/section/ul/li/a/span")
    .get_attribute("title")
    
    # replace the , and convert to int data type
    number_of_follower = int(str(follower).replace(",", ""));

    print(follower)
    print(number_of_follower)
```

Then you will have the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the "k" format (thousand) in multiple ways as follows:

- Using the *innerText* and `replace()` method:

  ```
  # follower_count = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li//a//span[contains(@title)]").text
  follower_count = "170k"
  print(int(follower_count.replace("k","000")))
  # 170000
  print(type(int(follower_count.replace("k","000"))))
  # <class 'int'>
  ```
- Using the *title* attribute and `re.sub()` method:

  ```
  # follower_count = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li//a//span[contains(@title)]").get_attribute("title")
  import re
  follower_count = "170,125"
  print(int(re.sub(',', '', follower_count)))
  # 170125
  print(type(int(re.sub(',', '', follower_count))))
  # <class 'int'>
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How use re.sub to convert selenium string to an Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983982/how-use-re-sub-to-convert-selenium-string-to-an-integer/65985453#65985453)
- [Convert a scraped string containing comma into an integer using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974990/convert-a-scraped-string-containing-comma-into-an-integer-using-python/65985135#65985135)